# Regular Expression to Check numeric field doesn't have /or have all same digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex

I have to validate a field. The field should be numeric, should not contain all the same digits (like 555555, 111111) . I need a regular expression to check this. I need to know how can I check if it contains all same digits.

tried few solutions like following but didn't worked

these three didn't work

```
var reg_exp = new RegExp('/^([0-9a-z])\1+$/gm'); 

var reg_exp = new RegExp('/^(\d)\1*$/');

var reg_exp = new RegExp('([0-9])\\1{5}');
```

This one working partly bcoz here it fixes to specific number of digits e.g. {6} in the expample to a specific number but i need a solution so that i can apply this to any number of digits

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var str = "111111112";
var reg_exp = new RegExp('([0-9]){6}');
alert(reg_exp.test(str));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

based on [http://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew](http://Wiktor%20Stribi%C5%BCew) tried this and it worked for string which have length more than 2

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "222";
var reg_exp = /^(\d)\1+$/; // new RegExp('([0-9]){6}');
alert(reg_exp.test(str));
}
```

returns `true`    and

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "221";
var reg_exp = /^(\d)\1+$/; // new RegExp('([0-9]){6}');
alert(reg_exp.test(str));
}
```

returns `false`

but the issue is that for

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "22";
var reg_exp = /^(\d)\1+$/; // new RegExp('([0-9]){6}');
alert(reg_exp.test(str));
}
```

or

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "11";
var reg_exp = /^(\d)\1+$/; // new RegExp('([0-9]){6}');
alert(reg_exp.test(str));
}
```

it returns `false`

I need a regex which can work for one digits numbers as well. and `var str = "1";` or `var str = "22";` should return `true`. Basically the numbers should have atleast two `unique` digits

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not a place to dump your requirements and expecting someone else to do your job for you.

Comment: Hint: via `\1` you can access match from group 1.

Comment: @MarcB: I thought the OP was clear, narrow, and specific in their post, and looking for help.  It would only take 10 seconds to make it a "question" if that's your beef.  Ironically, it is marked with one close vote as "too broad"...  If this is too broad, then I don't think there is *any* question that would satisfy SO anymore... -,-  What has happened to *helping* people?

Comment: @mellamokb, its more the fact that OP didn't even bother put forth the effort to even do a precursory google search before requirement dumping his "question" here.

Comment: "I need" is not a question. It's "do my job for me". I have no problem with HELPING people, but that means they show what they've attempted so far.

Comment: @Marc B , dear please have some manners as well along with some knowledge

Comment: @ZaveedAbbasi: I agree wholeheartedly!  This is not the way SO used to be.  It's like everybody forgets they were all newbs once too... Well hang in there :)

Comment: @Pshemo sorry added the wrong tag by mistake

Comment: @ZaveedAbbasi: and you should learn how to ask a proper question. I don't normally brag, but you may have noticed I do have a fair number of points on this site. That gives me certain privileges which you don't have.

Comment: @Marc B, privileges also require some patience and some respect, not intended to offence any one dear

Comment: Let me ask something related to the question: do you want to match `2`, too? Current answer and the one set as a dupe do not cover 1-digit strings. Wait: it was tagged Java, now it is JavaScript?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: the way it was asked, it assumes at least 2 digits, but what is the real intention...?

Comment: Well, I think the question is just unclear now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: edited the question properly, i think it should now be clear

Comment: Oh my, you used a RegExp object as a string literal inside a constructor - that is why your patterns did not work. [`var reg_exp = /^(\d)\1+$/;`](https://regex101.com/r/cQ1jV2/1) will match 2+ digit strings that only consist of the same digits. Is that what you need? However, you have `111111112` in your snippet and this string will not be matched with that regex as it contains 2 different digits. Or do you still need the [`var reg_exp = /^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d+$/;`](https://regex101.com/r/cQ1jV2/3)?

Comment: i need my field to have at least 2 distinct digits , 1 is invalid as 11 , and 12 or 21 is valid. let me try your solution bro

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : edited the question with proper need, kindly have a look at it

Comment: I am rather puzzled: `1` and `22` do not have *at least two unique digits*. Why do you expect true for these cases? Do you want to allow just any 1- and 2-digit strings? Please [**check this demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/kzj1k1y4/1/) - `/^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : yes i want to allow two digits string with 12 as valid and 22 as invalid. This worked for me , thanks a lot. can you please set it as answer so that i can mark it as answer

Comment: Let me clear out the last doubt: you are negating the result of the `test()`, aren't you? You want to use [`!/^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/.test("22")`](https://jsfiddle.net/kzj1k1y4/3/)?

Comment: Ok, posted, you can choose whether to negate or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex that will match an all-numeric string that has no 2 unique digits is

```
/^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM7wQ7/1).

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d)` - Group 1 that captures a single digit (the first one in the string)
- `(?:\1+)?` - an optional (as `?` matches one or zero occurrences) non-capturing group that matches the same digit that was captured with Group 1
- `$` - end of string.

In JS:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "22: " + /^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/.test("22") + " as there are no unique digits, 2-digit string";
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>12: " + /^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/.test("12") + " as there are 2 unique digits";
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>1: " + /^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/.test("1") + " as there is just 1 digit, no 2 unique digits";
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>-------- OR, with negation ----------";//or
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>22: " + !/^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/.test("22") + " as there are no unique digits, 2-digit string";
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>12: " + !/^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/.test("12") + " as there are 2 unique digits";
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>1: " + !/^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/.test("1") + " as there is just 1 digit, no 2 unique digits";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern (with the `matches` method that implicitly anchors the pattern on both sides):

```
(\d)\1*+\d+
```

*(don't forget to escape the backslashes in the string)*

The main idea is to use a possessive quantifier ( `*+` ) to forbid backtracking on the back-reference quantifier. Since this quantifier can't be used to backtrack, the following digit can only be different.

If you want to allow single digit strings, you can make the second part optional:

```
(\d)(?:\1*+\d+)?
```

or you can add an alternation:

```
(\d)\1*+\d+|\d
```

If you want to check the length of the string, *(you can obviously do it with the same regex)* use the `string.length()` method.

Comment: Can you explain the reason of your downvote? *(I don't think)*

Comment: Please vote to close as appropriate. If you have an answer, provide it in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Pillar Answer was created before question was closed so author may not know about duplicate.

Comment: @Pshemo But he is a gold badge holder for `regex`. They should know better. They've seen these questions for sure.

Comment: @Pillar: Do you believe that gold badge holders know all the question of SO? *(about 142000 only for the regex tag)*

Comment: All the questions? No. The basic ones in your field of expertise? Yes.

Comment: What's more, you're encouraging these garbage questions. You set a bad example. Please don't.